# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I've got this exception error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

when i try to execute my project.
**Route :**

```
     Route::get('ouvrircompte', function()
    {
        return View::make('user.ouvrircompte')
        ->with('title', 'Reserver');
         });


     Route::post('ouvrircompte', 'UserController@ouvrircompte');
```

**Controller :**

```
public function ouvrircompte()
{
$credentials = array(
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
    );

    try{
        $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
        $user_id=$user->id;
        if($user)
        {
            Session::put('user_id', $user_id);
            return Redirect::to('user/confirmReserver')->with('user_id', $user_id);
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        return Redirect::to('user/ouvrircompte')->withErrors(array('ouvrircompte' => $e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

**view :**

```
<form method="post" action="user/confirmReserver">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="ouvrircompte">Envoyer</button>
```

When i submit the form this shows me above error.

Comment: First off your post is pretty messed up, code-wise. You should fix it so that people can see all your code properly. However, I'd say one problem you have is that the form POSTS to the `user/confirmReserver` URI but, according to your code there's no such route. Maybe you need to update the form's action parameter?

Comment: Even when I modify the action to : <form method="post" action="'. URL::to('confirmReserver') .'"> I have the same problem

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing all your code/routes, but as far as I can tell the URI you're looking for is: `URL::to('ouvrircompte')`